# Hinge with Bones

Tags: rigging, bones, rigidbody

I am trying to rig up some landing gear and am having trouble trying to incorporate the door. On this particular airframe, there are three doors for the nose wheel: one in front of and attached the nose wheel strut via pushrods, and the other two are on each side of the wheel well that close hydraulically (so those are easy and not the issue). The nose wheel fairing (door) is hinged at the top and attached to the top of the nose wheel strut. When the gear retracts, the door is pulled shut via the attached pushrods (no hydraulics, just simple attachment).

I can get the pushrods to follow the upper mount, but the fairing will not stay attached to the bone. I have tried setting the fairing up as a rigid body with another mesh object (which is the wheel well bay, not shown) with a hinge constraint, which works as it should, other than it ignores the bone. I have also tried parenting the fairing to the bone so it pulls up with the bone, but it ignores the hinge.

So, it's like one or the other (with what I know of rigging). It doesn't have to be rigid body (meaning, it isn't a requirement, I was just trying to get anything to work).I just need the door to follow the bone/pushrod up but stay hinged. Any ideas/direction?

[image: EXTENDED]

[image: RETRACTED]

Comment: I would look at a file and offer my thoughts if you provided one.  Otherwise, I can't really understand the exact problem you're having from the question.  Preferred hosting here is https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure if the file would actually help. I realized I should have said the second picture is what it is supposed to look like. Essentially, I need to know if it is possible to hinge/anchor the door at the top ("hinge pt") and have a bone pull it around the hinge pt.